# resolving precedence of different math operators

Tags: java, math, operator-precedence

`deposit = sellingPrice == 0 ? 0 : (sellingPrice - interest)`

What is the above in terms of pseudo-code, I am rusty on ternary operators and operator precedence as complex as this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`deposit` is assigned `0` if `sellingPrice` equals `0` or `sellingPrice - interest` if not

same thing as

```
if(sellingPrice == 0){
     deposit = 0; 
}
else{
   deposit = (sellingPrice - interest);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If `sellingPrice == 0`  then  deposit = 0

else

```
deposit = (sellingPrice - interest)
```

[As per docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)

> Use the ?: operator instead of an if-then-else statement if it makes your code more readable;